# module 'config' has no attribute 'config_from_env'

Tags: python

This error appear despite of i installed lastest version of config library, can you help me or give me hint of how to solve this error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[129], line 3
      1 tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
      2 tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
----> 3 train_dataset, test_dataset = tokenize_and_split_data(training_config, tokenizer)
      5 print(train_dataset)
      6 print(test_dataset)

File ~\Downloads\AI najah\task2\utilities.py:112, in tokenize_and_split_data(training_config, tokenizer)
    111 def tokenize_and_split_data(training_config, tokenizer):
--> 112   initialized_config = initialize_config_and_logging(training_config)
    113   dataset_path = initialized_config["datasets"]["path"]
    114   use_hf = initialized_config["datasets"]["use_hf"]

File ~\Downloads\AI najah\task2\utilities.py:28, in initialize_config_and_logging(existing_config)
     26 def initialize_config_and_logging(existing_config=None):
     27     global global_config
---> 28     global_config = build_config(existing_config)
     29     setup_logging(global_config)
     30     logger.debug("Config: " + str(yaml.dump(global_config.as_dict())))

File ~\Downloads\AI najah\task2\utilities.py:41, in build_config(existing_config)
     38 def build_config(existing_config=None):
     39     configs = [
     40         # Using config library
---> 41         config.config_from_env(prefix="LLAMA", separator="_", lowercase_keys=True),
     42     ]
     44     if existing_config:
     45         if isinstance(existing_config, dict):

AttributeError: module 'config' has no attribute 'config_from_env
```

The code below is some functions of the utilities file that raise an error

```
import datasets
import tempfile
import logging
import random
import config
import os
import yaml
import logging
import time

import transformers

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
global_config = None

#############################
########## Permissions ##########
#############################
model_name_to_id = {
  "bigger_model_name" : "06ad41e68cd839fb475a0c1a4ee7a3ad398228df01c9396a97788295d5a0f8bb"
}

#############################
########## LOGGING ##########
#############################
def initialize_config_and_logging(existing_config=None):
    global global_config
    global_config = build_config(existing_config)
    setup_logging(global_config)
    logger.debug("Config: " + str(yaml.dump(global_config.as_dict())))
    return global_config

def get_config():
    global global_config
    assert global_config is not None
    return global_config

def build_config(existing_config=None):
    configs = [
        # Using config library
       config.config_from_env(prefix="LLAMA", separator="_", lowercase_keys=True),
    ]

    if existing_config:
        if isinstance(existing_config, dict):
            configs.append(config.config_from_dict(existing_config))
        else:
            configs.append(existing_config)

    config_paths = get_config_paths()
    for path in reversed(config_paths):
        print("Loading builtin config from " + path)
        configs.append(config.config_from_yaml(path, read_from_file=True))
    return config.ConfigurationSet(*configs)
```

try to upgrade the config and i think that there is an dependancy library should be upgrade Also I din't know about LOGGING or Permissions?

Comment: Do you happen to have a file called `config.py` in your directory by any chance…?

Comment: No i havn't @deceze

Comment: Please include code from utilities.py, especially how you imported config.

Comment: @ewokx I just added it

Comment: Where exactly is ```config``` imported?

Comment: @ewokx upper the code i added(the code i added it it just a some of functions that raise error in utilities  file not all the code of utilities  file)

Comment: Please include that part as well.  What config module is this?

Comment: @ewokx Also the code of utilities file is big i can't put all of it i put the upper part of the code in utilities file

Comment: What is the command that you used to install the ```config``` module?  Is it ```https://pypi.org/project/python-configuration/``` or ```https://pypi.org/project/config/```?

Comment: @ewokx I installed them and same error raise

Comment: This is confusing.  Which one are you intending to use.  The error probably stems from you using the syntax from one (python-configuration) when you're actually using the other (config).  Make sure you are clear which one you use and use that one's syntax.

Comment: @ewokx  Thanks for help I install this library "pip install accelerate -U", and also I didn't restart kernel after installed previous 2 libraries so i restart it and it run sucessfully

Comment: Try:
pip install python-configuration

Answer (score 0):

The config library can be found [there](https://github.com/tr11/python-configuration/blob/main/README.md).

```
pip install python-configuration
```